# Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

We just started learning about class inheritance and attribute lookup in python. I have a question about the following code:

```
class a : n = 1
class b : n = 2
class c : n = 3
class d (a,b) : pass
class e (d,c) : pass
```

I know that e.n would equal 1 due to the nature of attribute lookup procedure (depth first search). However, how would I access, say, class c's n from class e? I've tried e.c.n, but that gives me an error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> e.__bases__[1].n
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get there from here. Class attributes are replaced. Use the class reference directly (`c.n`).